# What does 'maxfev' do in iPython Notebook?

Tags: ipython, curve-fitting, jupyter

I was using the `curve_fit` function to find two coefficients and could not get a result until I altered something called `maxfev` to be a much larger value, since my error was that 'maxfev=600 has been reached', I took a total guess and added `maxfev=10000` into my `curve_fit` function and this seemed to work.
My question is: what is `maxfev`? What does it do, how does it work, and how has this affected my data?

Comment: Try not to increase maxfev too much; that usually means that something is wrong with the fit itself. Could you post your data and code!?

Answer (score 3):

The function `curve_fit` is a wrapper around `leastsq` (both from the scipy.optimize library). The parameter that you are adjusting specifies how many times the parameters for the model that you are trying to fit are allowed to be altered, while the program is attempting to find a local minimum (see below example).

```
data = [(1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3)...]
model = a*x+b
```

Let us assume that you initialize the `a` and `b` to `0`. The program attempts it once, gets a given array of leastsquares back, then the program will attempt to alter either `a` or `b` and run it again. This repeats itself until an optimal value for `a` and `b` were found (yielding the lowest least squares, which should be `a=1` and `b=-1`).

The fact that your program can not find the optimal value after 600 alterations of the parameters is a clear indication that you are fitting the wrong model.

PS: Your problem has nothing to do with the IPython Notebook